# How to create heatmap with tree in R or Python?

Tags: python, r

Example dataset has been given below. First column denotes ID and other three columns represent feature 1, feature 2, feature 3 respectively. N.B. Features values will be discrete always.

```
Id,f1,f2,f3
abc,1,1,2
def,1,1,3
ghi,2,3,1
```

I want to create a heatmap with tree. And similar ones will group together.

Example figure:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may try

```
library(tidyverse)


df <- read.table(text = "Id,f1,f2,f3
abc,1,1,2
def,1,1,3
ghi,2,3,1", header = T, sep =',')

df %>% column_to_rownames(var = "Id") %>% as.matrix() %>% heatmap
```

[image]

## Add

I'm not sure it will work with your data, but using `mtcars` dataset,

```
data <- as.matrix(mtcars)
heatmap(data, col= colorRampPalette(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(8, "Blues"))(3), Colv = NA)
```

[image]

(3) next at `colorRampPalette(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(8, "Blues"))(3)` part indicates how many colors you will use.

`Colv = NA` options removes upper tree and `Rowv` will control tree on the left.

Comment: I'm seeing more than three colors. I don't want more than 3 colors. Where is legend?

Comment: could you please help to figure out the issue?

Comment: And how to stop the upper dendrogram?

Comment: @RajanRaju Take a look at my additional part.

Comment: why white colors?